# how to implement redelivery policy for a specific endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have two web-service call in my fuse service. I need to implement retry when time out occurs in only one of the web service call.how can i achieve that in fuse.

Answer (score 0):

A redelivery policy can be specified for an Exception Clause (onException) or an Error Handler. Both of them can be applied to either global (per RouteBuilder instance) or route scope. So you'll have to put your web service calls into two separate routes.